# Increase Labelsize in Julia Plots

Tags: plot, julia, keyword-argument

I am creating a plot `using Plots` in Julia. I was trying to increase the size of the labels and also the values on the axes but couldn't find the right keyword arg (I thought it was `annotationfontsize` but that doesn't seem to work). Does anyone know the right arg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `guidefontsize` and `tickfontsize`. You can check all the axis attributes in the [documentation](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/attributes_axis/). For example,

```
julia> plot(rand(10); xtickfontsize=5, xlab="Big label, small tick labels", xguidefontsize=20)
```

will give you something like

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.